# Create a multi-line string from a set in React javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a React function where I am having a set and I want to update an HTML element using the data present in the set. Following is the code example:

```
const myFunc = (mySet) => {
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = Array.from(mySet).join(' ');
} 

...
// In the render code:
<p id="myId> </p>
```

This correctly joins the set elements using a blank space separator, but I want to have it displyed in the form of bulleted lists or in a new line.

Is it possible to have multiline append using innerHTML?

Ex: mySet = ('Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Drumstick')

Output on my code:
Apple Banana Carrot Drumstick

Output desirable:

Apple

Banana

Carrot

Drumstick

(or)

- Apple
- Banana
- Carrot
- Drumstick

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a little modification on `join` and change `innerHTML` to [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```
const myElement = document.getElementById('myId')
myElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin',Array.from(mySet).join('<br/>'));
```

But in my opinion, you should not manipulate DOM with `document` directly that is React's anti-pattern.

I'd suggest you use states to update your component

```
const [currentSet, setCurrentSet] = useState([])

const myFunc = (mySet) => {
    setCurrentSet(mySet);
} 

return <div id="myId">currentSet.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If mySet is an Array you should use React to render your items:

```
const myFunc = (mySet) => {
  
return(
   <ul>
      {mySet && mySet.map(val=>{return (<li>{val}</li>)})}
  </ul>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using innerText you could try:

```
Array.from(mySet).join('\n')
```

But if you are using innerHtml then try this:

```
Array.from(mySet).join('<br/>')
```

or you can map items with  tag:

```
Array.from(mySet).map(function(el) {return '<div>' + el + '</div>';}).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` expects a string therefore you are going to have to construct a string of elements as follows:

```
const myFunc = (mySet) => {
    const innerHTMLString = Array.from(mySet).map((item) => `<div>${item}</div>`).join('');
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = innerHTMLString;
  }
```

Then you can test it in the component as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const myFunc = (mySet) => {
    const innerHTMLString = Array.from(mySet).map((item) => `<div>${item}</div>`).join('');
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = innerHTMLString;
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={() => myFunc(new Set(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Drumstick']))>
      <p id="myId> </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [`Set.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) too

```js
const mySet = new Set(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Drumstick']);

let ulElm = '<ul>';
mySet.forEach((value) => ulElm += `<li>${value}</li>`);
ulElm += '</ul>';

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ulElm;
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```